# Running multiple independent apps with different frameworks (.NET and Flask) on same Azure web app service

Tags: c#, python, .net, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a website `<my-website-name>.azurewebsites.net`. This site is going to hold multiple small apps that are developed on different frameworks, something like this:

```
<my-website-name>.azurewebsites.net/app1 : Developed in Python Flask
<my-website-name>.azurewebsites.net/app2 : Developed in C# .NET
<my-website-name>.azurewebsites.net/ : Developed in C# .NET
```

The problem is I can not keep all of them up and running (please see attached pic)!

[Snapshot of my azure portal when I have 3 applications with different frameworks on same web app service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6t1F.png)

When python is ON, none of them load. When python is Off, only app1 does not load. They work when they are deployed on separate web app services tho.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me I have to containerize my apps. Ugh! Docker!